# Kivy: Buildozer.spec file is not completed

Tags: python, kivy, buildozer

I prepared *kivy buildozer* for using. For installation I used instructions [here](https://github.com/kivy/buildozer), process for python 3. After step 3, *buildozer.spec* file wasn't completed and checked lines (step 4) had next content:

```
requirements = kivy
#android.ndk_path =
```

Message about installation after *buildozer android debug deploy run*:

```
# Unpacking Android NDK
# Android NDK installation done.
# Check application requirements
# Check garden requirements
# Compile platform
# Command failed: /usr/bin/python -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=myapp --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=kivy --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir=/media/sf_ForBuildozer/.buildozer/android/platform/build
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# If the error is not obvious, please raise the log_level to 2
# and retry the latest command.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

What is origin of problems?

I added log_level = 2 to section *buildozer*, New message:

```
# Run '/usr/bin/python -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=myapp --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=kivy --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir=/media/sf_ForBuildozer/.buildozer/android/platform/build'
# Cwd /media/sf_ForBuildozer/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-new-toolchain
[INFO]:    Will compile for the following archs: armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    Found Android API target in $ANDROIDAPI
[INFO]:    Available Android APIs are ()
[WARNING]: Requested API target 19 is not available, install it with the SDK android tool.
[WARNING]: Exiting.
# Command failed: /usr/bin/python -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=myapp --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=kivy --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir=/media/sf_ForBuildozer/.buildozer/android/platform/build
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

I applied addvices of Mikhail Gerasimov and after short step I obtained new message:

```
# Run '/usr/bin/python -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=myapp --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=kivy --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir=/media/sf_ForBuildozer/.buildozer/android/platform/build'
# Cwd /media/sf_ForBuildozer/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-new-toolchain
[INFO]:    Will compile for the following archs: armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    Found Android API target in $ANDROIDAPI
[INFO]:    Available Android APIs are ()
[WARNING]: Requested API target 19 is not available, install it with the SDK android tool.
[WARNING]: Exiting.
# Command failed: /usr/bin/python -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=myapp --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=kivy --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir=/media/sf_ForBuildozer/.buildozer/android/platform/build
```

Comment: Read the error you posted and follow the instructions.

Comment: Add line `log_level = 2` to your `buidozer.spec` file (inside section `[buildozer]`).

Comment: Before my first question I added log_level = 2,but in incorrect line. I repaired it and new message I added to my question above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem here is that SDK doesn't contain all stuff to make build for target API. Usually buildozer handles it automatically, but from time to time [it breaks](https://github.com/kivy/buildozer/issues/146). You can install stuff manually through GUI (see link above) or as I usually do it through (linux) console:

```
echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/android update sdk --all --no-ui --filter tools
echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/android update sdk --all --no-ui --filter platform-tools
echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/android update sdk --all --no-ui --filter build-tools-27.0.2
echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/android update sdk --all --no-ui --filter android-19
```

Make sure your SDK dir avaliable at `android-sdk-linux/tools/android`.
After installing all this I think error should go.

Comment: с новым годом! I obtain first experiences now with linux via oracle virtualbox (machine: https://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-android-vm.html). I cann't find folder with Android SDK. Cann you help me?

Comment: @jasan thanks! If you didn't manually specify path to Android SDK in `buildozer.spec` it downloads SDK to default directory. If I'm not mistaken you'll find SDK in this folder - `~/.buildozer/android/platform/`. Folder `.buildozer/` is located in "user" directory, so full path will look like `/home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-20/`. If I'm mistaken run this command in linux console to search for folder `ls -d /home/*/android-sdk*` (it should print path to SDK).

Comment: I applied your advices and result you cann see above. Content of android-sdk-linux/tools/android you cann download from storage: http://leteckaposta.cz/714888255. Cann you continue with support, please?

Comment: @jasan ok, we found where `android-sdk-linux` folder located. Now you should open console in this location (in folder where folder `android-sdk-linux` exists) or just open console and change folder with [cd command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cd_(command)). Once you've done it you should run in console commands from my answer: each command executes `android` scrip with specific parameters. It will make SDK to download stuff it need for correct work. After all for commands been correctly executed, you can try `buildozer android debug deploy run` again.

Comment: I done your advice. Last information about installing SDK was:"Installing Android SDK Tools, revision 24.0.2
    Installed Android SDK Tools, revision 24.0.299%)
    Stopping ADB server succeeded.
    Starting ADB server succeeded.
null  Done. 49 packages installed."
I didn't find folder SDK, only at . ./android_sdk_20/tools/lib are folders type sdk**.jar. Detailed informations extend content comment. Can you recommend other way for next communication?

Comment: @jasan please write a question in [Kivy user support group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/kivy-users) including all steps you've done and all messages/errors you've got. It's more convenient to talk there and more people there who can try to help.

Comment: I sent contribution to "Kivy user support group", topic: Packing kivy for android with buildozer with bad nick "ja"

Comment: If it helps anyone, using the command `android-sdk-linux/tools/android` (or your path to the SDK) a GUI interface shows up with the updated version numbers for each installable package.